# Adobesign authentication token error via postman

Tags: postman, adobe, rest

I have tried to get the authentication token from adobe size and always get the return "Invalid grant_type parameter value"
[image: REQUEST THROUGH POST MAN]
I have used the grant_type and code are same (Authorization code) and the code return from https://secure.adobesign.com/public/oauth

Urgent help needs if anyone has experience.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at rest of your parameters, value of the `grant_type` parameter should be `authorization_code`. In general, you can find more on OAuth protocol at https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/.
You might also find [Adobe developers documentation](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/sign/docs.html#!adobedocs/adobe-sign/master/gstarted/get_access_token.md) helpful. Example request from the page:

```
POST http://api.adobesign.com/oauth/token?
   code=CBNCKBAThIsIsNoTaReAlcs_sL4K32wCzs4N&
   client_id=CBAThIsIsNoTaReAlmPBvPF&
   client_secret=319UThIsIsNoTaReAl2-4OxkVo9ycU&
   redirect_uri=https://myserver.com&
   grant_type=authorization_code HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the authorization_code? I got to authorization_code follow this process "Note the code CBNCKBAThIsIsNoTaReAlcs_sL4K32wCzs4N in the request. This is the authorization code that you will use to get the OAuth access token." follow the adobe developer documentation.

Comment: `authorization_code` is a literal. Put it as value of `grant_type`.

Comment: Also, try with authorization_code as a value of grant_type unfortunately it is not working.